# Problem Ubuntu 16.04 wifi infrastructure mode

Tags: drivers, wireless, network-manager, mode

I have recently updated my laptop from Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 16.04

For my university internet connection I must use infrastructure mode in the wifi configuration.

When I try to set up the university network with  "Network Connections" in Ubuntu 16.04 there are only three options for mode: client,Hotspot and Ad-hoc. The infrastructure mode option was present in Ubuntu 14.04 but in Ubuntu 16.04 is not an option anymore.

I am sure that is not a hardware problem since everything was working fine with Ubuntu 14.04.

Is it a driver problem?

Is it a "Network Connections" problem?

The output of `lspci` is:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
```

Comment: I am using wireless on lubuntu 16.04 LTS and I only see the same three modes you describe. This makes me think it is not hardware issue also since my adapter is a RT280USB stick. Looks like what you are looking for is described here:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2329259 That final post looks like someone with a similar use-case to yourself so maybe there is still a problem with 16.04 for you.

Comment: Why are you trying to create a new connection? Do yo uwant to connect to your university access point?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem in Ubuntu 16.04 as the wifi worked fine in 15.10 before installation (clean install)  and it work fine in Windows 7/10), I do not know the reason but I fixed the problem partially as follows:

1. You have to know what your wifi interface is, so open a terminal and type:

   ```
   ifconfig
   ```

   The output should show something like

   ```
   enp0s10   Link encap:Ethernet  direcciónHW 00:14:85:2d:d9:20
         ACTIVO DIFUSIÓN MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Métrica:1
         Paquetes RX:0 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 frame:0
         Paquetes TX:0 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
         colisiones:0 long.colaTX:1000
         Bytes RX:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

   lo        Link encap:Bucle local
         Direc. inet:127.0.0.1  Másc:255.0.0.0
         Dirección inet6: ::1/128 Alcance:Anfitrión
         ACTIVO BUCLE FUNCIONANDO  MTU:65536  Métrica:1
         Paquetes RX:2465 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 frame:0
         Paquetes TX:2465 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
         colisiones:0 long.colaTX:1
         Bytes RX:284298 (284.2 KB)  TX bytes:284298 (284.2 KB)

   wlp1s8    Link encap:Ethernet  direcciónHW 00:1d:1a:01:53:81
         Direc. inet:192.168.0.155  Difus.:192.168.0.255  Másc:255.255.255.0
         Dirección inet6: fe80::abe5:47fa:aee0:f1fc/64 Alcance:Enlace
         ACTIVO DIFUSIÓN FUNCIONANDO MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Métrica:1
         Paquetes RX:4150850 errores:0 perdidos:1 overruns:0 frame:0
         Paquetes TX:3166922 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
         colisiones:0 long.colaTX:1000
         Bytes RX:5126859398 (5.1 GB)  TX bytes:389946883 (389.9 MB)
   ```

   As you see, my interface is `wlp1s8`.
2. Open the file `/etc/rc.local` with root permissions:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/rc.local
   ```

   You'll see something like this:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh -e
   #
   # rc.local
   #
   # This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
   # Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
   # value on error.
   #
   # In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
   # bits.
   #
   # By default this script does nothing.

   exit 0
   ```

   Add the line

   ```
   iwconfig wlp1s8 rate 54M
   ```

   before `exit 0`, where `wlp1s8` is your wlan interface, so that the edited file looks like this

   ```
   #!/bin/sh -e
   #
   # rc.local
   #
   # This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
   # Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
   # value on error.
   #
   # In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
   # bits.
   #
   # By default this script does nothing.

   iwconfig wlp1s8 rate 54M    

   exit 0
   ```
3. Restart your computer to apply changes.

This has fixed the problem partially; before this I lost the signal completely and the Internet was very slow. Now I don't lose the signal but the Internet speed falls after time (15-20 min.) from 1.6 mb. down/350 kb up to 350 kb. down/20 kb up.

Comment: PS: You can also try to restart the network interface: `# sudo service networking restart`.

Comment: FYI: when answering a question in English (as on AskUbuntu), it is helpful to set your system’s language to English using `export LANG=C` or `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` (etc) before running the commands and copying their output.

Comment: also consider [sudoedit](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sudoedit) instead of `sudo nano` ([why?](http://www.wingtiplabs.com/blog/posts/2013/03/13/sudoedit/))

Answer (score 0):

Infrastructure mode and Client mode are one and the same. To connect to your university wifi, please use Client mode.

Answer (score 0):

I finally made it work after several tries.

I think there is a problem with NetworkManager tool. Here is what I did:

1.-I disabled the "NetworkManager".

2.-I install "Wicd NetworkManager".

3.- Create a wifi connection  with "Network Connections" tool and used "client mode" instead of "infrastructure mode".

4.-I connect to the university network with "Wicd".

I dont know how this is working, but now I am able to connect to university wifi.  Setting only "client mode" instead of "infrastructure mode" and using the "NetworkManager" was not solving the problem.